# How to share Storage between Chrome extension page and popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a following context:

1. Chrome extension
2. `index.html` page located at `chrome-extension://extensionID/public/index.html`
3. `popup.html` that shows up on click at extension icon from Chrome extension tab
4. user at `index.html` fill up form with certain fields (`a`, `b`, `c`) and JS stores them in [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#property-local)
5. when user clicks on extension icon popup shows up and user sees the data he entered on step 4

---

Ideally, I want to share the same `chrome.storage.local` between `popup.html` and `index.html` but as I understand they have isolated environments and they doesn't have access to each other.

I didn't found any docs related how to send information from extension specific web-page (i.e. `chrome-extension://extensionID/public/index.html`) to extension popup.
But I found [information about messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#simple) between service worker and content-script.

Any ideas and approaches on how to share information from `index.html` to `popup.html`?

Thanks.

Comment: May be this will help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414495/chrome-storage-between-popup-and-browser-action-window

Comment: "but as I understand they have isolated environments" <- no, it's the same throughout the extension

Comment: Any proofs, links maybe @AndrewParks?